# HTML Trying to get value from textbox and use it for a math equation in Javascript(Volume)

Tags: javascript, html, math, volume

I would like to make it so it pulls the value I input into the textbox into the variables l w and h then does the equation l*w*h and presents the answer im not that good at coding I just started and soon im going to be taking computer science I would really appreciate the help

`
        
        
        
        Volume

```
    body,input{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #CC0000;
}

  </style>

  </head>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function RP(){
 var l = document.getElementById('Length').value=l;

 var w  = document.getElementById('Width').value=w;

 var h  = document.getElementById('Height').value=h;

 var answer = l*w*h  
 document.getElementById('Answer').value=answer;

}
</script>

<body>
<form>
<button id="roll" onclick="RP()">Button</button>

<p>Rectangular Prism

<p>Length:
 <input type="text" id='Length' size="3"/>
 <br/>

 Width:
 <input type="text" id='Width'  size= "3"/>
 <br/>

 Height:
 <input type="text" id='Height'  size= "3"/>
 <br/>

 Answer:
 <input type="text" id='Answer'  size="3" disabled='disabled'/>
 <br/>
 <form/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your JavaScript function.  You are assigning the variable twice which causes some confusion.  Your RP() function should look like this:

```
function RP() {
    var l = document.getElementById('Length').value;

    var w = document.getElementById('Width').value;

    var h = document.getElementById('Height').value;

    var answer = l * w * h;

    document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/ZFFQd/

Comment: It seems that my function isn't the only problem it still wont work even taking your answers into account.

Comment: Something you haven't posted is the issue then, see the Fiddle I just posted.  It works as you described.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/ZFFQd/

Comment: I think I fixed it I have no idea what the problem really was but it got fixed thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

You've got some extra '=' signs, I think. Instead try:

```
var l = document.getElementById('Length').value;

 var w  = document.getElementById('Width').value;

 var h  = document.getElementById('Height').value;
```

You might also want to ensure that only numbers are used in the equation so try:

```
var l = parseInt(document.getElementById('Length').value);
```

Comment: doh! - beaten to it by @Duffmaster33 by 2 seconds

Comment: :) Also, I believe parseInt is not required here since it's multiplication.  Of course, if someone puts in non-numeric characters, the result will be NaN, but that goes more to validation.